# Android: how to place the text of a textview in the middle of its parent

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I've been looking for an answer reading other questions, but i 've not found exactly what i want.
I have a **TextView** contained in a LinearLayout, with attributes *android:layout_height* and *android:layout_width* set to *match_parent*.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mylayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytextview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@string/mytext"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mytextsize" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I want the TextView text to start in the middle of the LinearLayout; I mean, to position the text vertically to the middle of the LinearLayout, but keeping *android:layout_height="match_parent"* in **TextView**.

It is possible??

In my java code in onCreate method I have this to get the middle point of the parent:

```
LinearLayout myLinearlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
myLinearLayout.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int linearLayoutHeight = myLinearLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
int middlePoint = linearLayoutHeight / 2;
```

Now, I dont know how to position the top line of the text in that point. Thanks

** EDIT 1 **

I forgot mention that the textview is scrollable, and the text is too long.

Comment: What you have, should work as you describe.

Comment: Have you tied to add `android:gravity="center"` in the `<LinearLayout...>`?

Comment: But with android:gravity="center" i can center all text in the middle of its parent, but no to place the very top line of the text to the middle of its parent.

Comment: I'm adding an answer that will help you, but it won't be perfect.

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/mylayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytextview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="@string/mytext"
    android:textSize="@dimen/mytextsize"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/mytext"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mytextsize" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add a 50% empty block above your `TextView`, to give the illusion that your TextView starts slightly below the middle of the `LinearLayout`.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mylayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytextview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@string/mytext"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mytextsize" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes! but TextView is scrollable and i want to scroll to the top of the parent view. I want textview to be as parent height Thankss :)

Comment: I don't understand, please clarify.

Comment: Well, i have a textView with android:layout_height="match_parent", and this attribute dont want to change it because i have set up ScrollingMovementMethod() on textView, and the first line of the text must be in the middle and then scrolls all the text to the top of the textView, like it had white space in text at the beginning, do you undestand my idea?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

//Center TextView

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/header_footer_bankground_border_color"
    android:orientation="veritcal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_welcome"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Some text here"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```